# When using Pascal case for class name, what should I do about classes that I want to prefix with iOS

Tags: c#, naming-conventions

So I have various platform Specific classes in my code:

```
class WindowsImplementation ...

class AndroidImplementation ...
```

but what do I do about:

```
class iOSImplementation

class IOSImplementation
```

?

`iOS` breaks the (Pascal) class naming convetion but `IOS`looks a little strange.

Comment: IosImplementation? It looks like a, for example, System.Xml.Linq.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions

If you take the view that iOS is an acronym, consider using `Ios`.

> The PascalCasing convention, used for all identifiers except parameter
>   names, capitalizes the first character of each word (including
>   acronyms over two letters in length), as shown in the following
>   examples: